# wait for props to be updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this component which call `fetchSpecificBook` action creator:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchSpecificBook } from '../actions/index';

class Cart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderWishlist = this.renderWishlist.bind(this);
  }

  renderWishlist(){
    var quantity;
    var itemID;
    var tmp;
    var myData = this.props.currentCart;
    for (var k=0; k<myData.length; k++){
     tmp = myData[k];
     quantity = tmp.quantity;
     itemID = tmp.itemID;
     fetchSpecificBook(itemID);
     console.log(this.props.currentBook);  // prints undefined
   }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>Your wishlist</h3>
            {this.renderWishlist()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    currentCart: state.bookReducer.currentCart,
    currentBook: state.bookReducer.currentBook
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchSpecificBook})(Cart);
```

fetchSpecificBook action creator look like this:

```
export function fetchSpecificBook(id) {
  let url = 'http://localhost:3001/specific-book/'+id;
  return function (dispatch) {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_BOOK,
          payload: response
        });
      });
    }
}
```

and my reducer:

```
import {FETCH_BOOKS} from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = { currentBook:[] };

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_BOOK:
      return { ...state, currentBook:action.payload };
    ... other cases
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So when my component is being rendered it loads `renderWishlist()` which invokes `fetchSpecificBook` action creator that sends the action to the reducer. Here `currentBook` gets updated and in my component I can access to `currentBook` thanks to `mapStateToProps`.

My question is: How can I wait until `currentBook` has been updated?
As you can see from my comment in the code above `console.log(this.props.currentBook);` returns undefined.
I guess because I'm trying to print `this.props.currentBook` which is not updated by the reducer yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple of things:

1. Your cart will receive fetchSpecificBook on its props. That is the function you should use, not the one you import. (so use this.props.fetchSpecificBook())
2. You shouldnt call fetchSpecificBook in renderWishlist, but in a lifecycle method like componentDidMount. When the reducer has new state, it will feed new props to your component, and render() is triggered. Because your render() calls renderWishList, it will trigger fetchSpecificBook AGAIN. This will go on and on.

Its important that render() only renders and doesnt produce side-effects like ajax calls.

Now, for your question: The initial state of currentBook is an empty array (which is strange, an empty object {} or undefined would make more sense..).
This is the initial state you will receive as props in your component. When the axios call is done, you will receive the response of that as your new props.
So, you can't really 'wait' for the book to be updated, but what you can do is in your render method: check if the value is different than the initial state, and only then console log or do something else. If you make your initial state 'undefined' instead of an empty array for example, you can do this in your render method:

```
{ this.props.currentBook && this.renderWishList() }
```

This will only call this.renderWishList() if this.props.currentBook has a value.

Comment: Good answer! For your second point though, i'd rather use `fetchSpecificBook` on `componentDidMount`, not in the constructor - for the sake of good practice.

Comment: agreed. Edited for clarity.